# google maps integration and SlidingMenu

Tags: android, google-maps, menu, maps, slider

I want to implement Google maps v2 and SliderMenu of jfeinstein10, I managed to implement the SliderMenu but when I want to add the map in the activity, I get error

GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager (). FindFragmentById (R.id.fragMapa)). GetMap ();

being more specific in getSupportFragmentManager ()

any solution for that integrate both. I put the code of the activity.

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivity;

public class ActivityPrincipal extends SlidingActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_principal);

        GoogleMap mapa = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragMapa)).getMap();

        LatLng coordenadasGT = new LatLng(15.45368,-90.485115);
        CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(coordenadasGT)
        .zoom(8)
        .build();

        CameraUpdate camUpd = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);

        mapa.moveCamera(camUpd);
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_principal, menu);
        return true;
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: You haven't actually provided any information about the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to integrate Google maps v2 and SliderMenu of jfeinstein10.
My Activity extends ActionBarActivity and i am using slider menu by constructing it programmatically :

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
            menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_OF);
            menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
            menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
            menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
            menu.setMenu(R.layout.options);
            menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
            menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
            menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
            menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
            menu.setOnOpenedListener(this);

            FragmentManager fmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment = fmanager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
            SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragment;

            mMap = supportmapfragment.getMap();
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
            mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
    }
```

mapView is a Fragment in my layout:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```