# How to use jfeinstein sliding menu with a mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview, slidingmenu, jfeinstein

How do i integrate jfeinstein sliding  menu with a mapview inside it? I tried using the code in this post [google maps integration and SlidingMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074394/google-maps-integration-and-slidingmenu) but it still doesnt work.

Comment: You have to define what "still doesn't work" means, because it could mean anything.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It's acutally quite easy, go to the [Github repo](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/master/library-maps-support/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app) and download the java class appropriate. This `slidingMapActivity` will fix the issue.

Then in you acitiy, change the `extend` of **Acitivty** to **SlidingMapActivity** and that it.